# como cambiar una clase por otra

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente problema

Necesito cambiar la clase pull-right  por pull-left es en esta linea que aparece

```
<div class="pull-right search input-group">
```

He intentado esto pero no funciona

```
$('.search .input-group').removeClass('pull-right');
```

Aquí la intentaba eliminar para después agregarle `pull-left`, pero realmente si se pudiera cambiar ahorraría tiempo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero es recalcar que el selector `$('.search .input-group')` no te funcionará en este casó por que estás diciendo que el elemento de clase `.input-group` se encuentra dentro de otro elemento con clase `.search` y en este caso el elemento tiene ambas clases por lo cual debes eliminar el esacio en blanco que las separa: `$('.search.input-group')`

Desde **jQuery** veo dos opciones que puedes utilizar:

La primera es simplemente remover la clase `pull-right` y añadir la clase `pull-left`:

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('.search.input-group')
  .removeClass('pull-right')
  .addClass('pull-left')
})
```

```css
.pull-right{
  float: right !important;
}

.pull-left{
  float: left !important;
}

button{
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pull-right search input-group">
  <p>Hola mundo</p>
</div>

<button id="btn">Cambiar</button>
```

Otra opción que me parece viable es utilizar el método [toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) para añadir o agregar una clase según el caso:

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('.search.input-group')
  .toggleClass('pull-left')
})
```

```css
.search{
  float: right !important;
}

.pull-left{
  float: left !important;
}

button{
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="search input-group">
  <p>Hola mundo</p>
</div>

<button id="btn">Cambiar</button>
```

La opción que te postula **Andres Sandoval** en su respuesta es propia de [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) la cual es una librería de interacciones y efectos de interfaz de usuario creada sobre la biblioteca de **jQuery** por lo cual tendrías que añadirla a tu proyecto.

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('.search.input-group')
  .switchClass('pull-right', 'pull-left')
})
```

```css
.pull-right{
  float: right !important;
}

.pull-left{
  float: left !important;
}

button{
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="pull-right search input-group">
  <p>Hola mundo</p>
</div>

<button id="btn">Cambiar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias por su explicacion y su tiempo, me funciono perfecto

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas eliminar el espacio entre las clases de tu selector.  Luego solo agregas la clase que quieres con `addClass()` asi:

```js
$('.search.input-group').removeClass('pull-right').addClass('pull-left');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pull-right search input-group">div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar el metodo `switchClass` de jquery UI, asi:

```
$('.search.input-group').switchClass('pull-right', 'pull-left');
```

esto cambiara la clase 'pull-right' por 'pull-left'

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero necesitas eliminar el espacio entre las clases para que funcione el selector.

Comment: Andres gracias por responder al ejecutar tu codigo me genera el siguiente error: switchClass is not a function

Comment: Revisa la version de JQuery que usas...puedes encontrar referencia en https://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/

Comment: switchClass es de jQuery UI por lo cual tendría que agregar dicha librería